# Picker gives me an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, why is this happening?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, picker

I need my picker to hide elements if authorization == true.

```
    private async void Picker_Unfocused(object sender, FocusEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            await DisplayAlert("try", picker.SelectedIndex.ToString(), "OK");

            if (response.domains[picker.SelectedIndex].authorization == true)
            {
                userNameEntry.IsVisible = false;
                passwordEntry.IsVisible = false;
                userLabel.IsVisible = false;
            }
            else
            {
                userNameEntry.IsVisible = true;
                passwordEntry.IsVisible = true;
                userLabel.IsVisible = true;
            }
        }
        catch(System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException)
        {
            await DisplayAlert("catch", picker.SelectedIndex.ToString(), "OK");
        }
    }
```

This won't help. I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException. Does anyone know why? It is important to me that this works.

Edit: Code is now current code. displayalerts just give me 0 if I select the first item, 1 if I select the second, etc. I still don't know what's going on. If the value of `SelectedIndex` is 0(or whatever I select) I shouldn't get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException, right?

Comment: assuming that `picker` is a dropdown, there's every possibility that `SelectedIndex = -1` which would be one reason for the exception.

Comment: Either nothing is selected and it's -1 or `response.domain` has a size that is different from `picker`.

Comment: **Use your debugger!**  What is the value of `picker.SelectedIndex` and how does that compare with the bounds of the `response` collection?

Comment: @BarryO'Kane I have tried, and I am actually selecting an item before doing this, the value is 0, so the first item is selected.

Comment: When you say 'the value is 0' I assume that you mean the value of `picker.SelectedIndex`. Put a break point on that first line (`if (respo......`) and check that `domains` is not null, and has at least 1 item.

Comment: @BarryO'Kane It has 6 items, I fill the picker with response.domains too

Answer (score 1):

When the picker is not yet initialized or can view a null value and is thus empty, the `SelectedIndex` property will give you a value of `-1`. This value is not valid for use in an array.

You should enrich your code to account for this possibility, for instance like this:

```
if (picker.SelectedIndex > -1 && response.domains[picker.SelectedIndex].authorization == true)
{
    userNameEntry.IsVisible = false;
    passwordEntry.IsVisible = false;
    userLabel.IsVisible = false;
}
else
{
    userNameEntry.IsVisible = true;
    passwordEntry.IsVisible = true;
    userLabel.IsVisible = true;
}
```

Comment: I checked, and the 'SelectedIndex' property is giving me a value of 0 though. I select an item, then the code above is in Picker_Unfocused. So when the picker is unfocused a few visual items should hide. But I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException even though I've selected an item and the value is 0.